# Bootstrap - Container to size of screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm designing a page in Bootstrap and theres a container i need to always fill the whole screen regardless of screen size. Is there a simple technique for doing this? User will still be able to scroll, but need to ensure when the page loads that container is always before the fold.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: How about using [Bootstrap's `.container-fluid`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/overview/#containers) class that creates a full width content container?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your code in a block with class `container-fluid`

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
<div id="main-div" class="container-fluid main_container">

   <div class="row">
    
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

class name `container-fluid` will use full width.

for height you'll need to use your own css for that.

set height and width to 100vw ( =100% view width) and 100vh ( =100% view height) or 90vh if you want it slightly shorter than the page height.

```
.full-page {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

if you also need to make room for other elements like a navigation bar you can account for it using calc()

```
height: calc(100vh - 50px);
```